# How can I display image data in next view by using Storyboards in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uistoryboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass image ID to next view by using Storyboards in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516734/how-can-i-pass-image-id-to-next-view-by-using-storyboards-in-ios)

My code is:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
    DestinationViewController *destinationViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Destination"];

    destinationViewController.title = @"image property";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES];

    [destinationViewController release];    
}
```

But i got error is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x68a0840>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'Destination''
 First throw call stack:
(0x13d4022 0x1565cd6 0x448fef 0x39f6 0x13d5e99 0x2114e 0x210e6 0xc7ade 0xc7fa7 0xc7266 0x463c0 0x465e6 0x2cdc4 0x20634 0x12beef5 0x13a8195 0x130cff2 0x130b8da 0x130ad84 0x130ac9b 0x12bd7d8 0x12bd88a 0x1e626 0x2902 0x2875)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the view controller's identifier to "Destination" in IB.  The following iextracted from Apple's document on UIStoryBoard.

An identifier string that uniquely identifies the view controller in the storyboard file. You set the identifier for a given view controller in Interface Builder when configuring the storyboard file. This identifier is not a property of the view controller object itself and is only used by the storyboard file to locate the view controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

method to pass data between view controllers using

```
myViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

to specify your destination.

Answer (score 0):

The answer involving setting the identifier correctly is probably your problem. However, it seems like you're doing this in a kind of hacky way by getting a reference to the storyboard and having it instantiate the controller.

Instead, try creating a push segue between the view controller and the `DestinationViewController` in the storyboard editor and do this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierHere"];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DestinationViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    [controller setImage: ... ];
}
```

Comment: (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Destination" sender:self];
    
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DestinationViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    //[controller setImage: ... ];